# How to redirect multiple outputs of one command to multiple files in Unix?

Tags: unix, io-redirection

I am a beginner for Unix and I am trying do the following things:

```
time ls
```

This cmd will display the result of ls and timestamp on the screen. I can put the result of "ls" into a file by

```
time ls > ls_result.out
```

Or I can put both results of ls and time into a file by

```
(time ls) > both.out
```

But I want to know how can I separate them and put result of time command into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

```
(time ls > ls_out ) 2> time_out
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is said "badly placed () 's".

Thanks,

Comment: @BobW It worked for me on Cygwin Bash. Your shell might be other than bash -- try `echo $0` to see which one you are using. I can also try it on Linux tonight. Meanwhile, the link to a duplicate of this question on top has some very good answers, you should check it out.